# dynamic variable qweb odoo v8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I have a web page where I need to create a number of fields and variables dynamically.

Let me explain : On page One, I have a text field where i have to type the number of users I want. That number is passed as parameter to the next page (post method) and collected as nb_user on page Two.

In the template.xml of page Two i have this code :

```
  <form method="POST" class="col-md-8" action="/page_three">


  <t t-foreach="nb_user" t-as="user">
    <input type="text" name="comp_1_user_1" id="comp_1_user_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Computer user"/>

   </t>


<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Validate"/>
```

What I would like is that based on the number that is passed in post (nb_user), it should dynamically create that amount of text fields ans also create unique id (comp_1_user_1, comp_1_user_2 etc....) so that i can enter that data into my database.

So if the parameter was 3 then it should create 3 text fields and create 3 variables comp_1_user_1, comp_1_user_2, comp_1_user_3.

I hope I was clear enough .
I am very new to Odoo and Qweb.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can I see the code for your model class or are you adding the data directly to the database?

Comment: Hi. The data is transferred to a model which adds it to the DB. But that part work fine. It's just that I need to generate text fields and their attributes dynamically , based on a parameter I get on the previous page( integer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mix literals with non-literals, use the `tf-attf-$name` attribute where `$name` stands for the attribute needed. As parameter you can then use a format-string, in your case:

```
<t t-foreach="nb_user" t-as="user">
    <input type="text" 
           t-attf-name="comp_1_user_{{ user }}"
           t-attf-id="comp_1_user_{{ user }}" 
           class="form-control" 
           placeholder="Computer user"/>
</t>
```

This will be evaluated by QWeb to be the attribute `name` (and `id` respectively) with the contents evaluated as a format string. That is, the string `comp1_user_` is passed as it is and the contents of the `{{ user }}` snippet is evaluated as Python code.

Run with an array containing `[1,2,3]` instead of `nb_user` like so

```
<t t-foreach="[1,2,3]" t-as="user">
    <input type="text" 
    t-attf-name="comp_1_user_{{ user }}" 
    t-attf-id="comp_1_user_{{ user }}"
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Computer user"/>
</t>
```

leads to

[image]

with `name` and `id` iterating over `comp_1_user_1`, `comp_1_user_2` and `comp_1_user_3`. Screenshot from Chrome DevTools:

[image]

For more information [see docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html#attributes).

Comment: Thanks a lot datafile. It works file with a list [1,2,3]. But in my case, I need to pass a parameter, as the number of fields needs to be dynamic and collected in the previous page. How can I do that ??

Comment: Your solution works fine. I just had to convert to int before passing it as a parameter. Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated